# JS call to function in php page - syntax issue

Tags: javascript, php

HI i tring to call a js function in PHP file using `echo "";` and it's not working, if I call it without the `echo` it's work, what am I missing here ?

this way it's is work:

```
<a href='#' onClick='delfrmvbar("dlsyg","<?php echo $sgId;?>","<?php echo $sgId;?>")'>X</a>&nbsp;</span>
```

and this way is not (I tried without the - ' sign)

```
echo "<a href='#' onClick='delfrmvbar('dlsyg','$sgId','$sgId')'>X</a>&nbsp;</span>";
```

Comment: Why do you pass the same argument twice to your `delfrmvbar` function?

Comment: I am not, it's just for example, I just forgot to change the name of the third variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single quotes are the issue because you use single quotes to wrap the onclick attribute, but then use them again around the arguments.

Example solution: use double quotes around the attribute and escape.

```
echo "<a href='#' onClick=\"delfrmvbar('dlsyg','$sgId','$sgId')\">X</a>&nbsp;</span>";
```

This will render the HTML like below, which is syntactically correct:

```
<a href='#' onClick="delfrmvbar('dlsyg','xx','xx')">X</a>&nbsp;</span>
```